# Django - replacing built-in templatetag by custom tag for a whole site without {% load .. %}

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to replace the standard `{% if %}` template tag with a "smart if" custom tag from [this snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1350/), because I don't want to write `{% load smart_if %}` every time. Also, "smart if" will come into core template system [very soon](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Version1.2Features).

I forgot where I saw a piece of code that does this. Does anyone know how to replace a built-in templatetag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a full solution to replace the "if" tag, but you can [automatically load template tags](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/342/).

Comment: Thanks! It's a best solution for me

Answer (score 6):

Place this somewhere you know will get run:

```
from django.template import add_to_builtins
add_to_builtins('mysite.myapp.templatetags.smart_if')
```

... while placing smart_if.py containing the smart_if code at the appropriate location. This effectively overrides the if tag with "smart if" accross the whole site.